# Count unique values by column

Tags: r

I looked for this answer for quite awhile but didn't find anything, so here it is... How can I count the number of distinct values by-column, given the following data frame?

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(NA, NA, NA), z = c(NA, NA, 1))
> df
  x  y  z
1 1 NA NA
2 2 NA NA
3 3 NA  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try in `base R`:

```
#Code
apply(df,2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Output:

```
x y z 
3 1 2
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple base R option using `lengths` + `unique`

```
> lengths(sapply(df,unique))
x y z
3 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(where(function(x){TRUE}), n_distinct)) %>% distinct()
```

This simply applies `dplyr`'s `n_distinct` function column-wise. The `where(function(x){TRUE})` will return `TRUE` for every column, and is basically a way of selecting-all within the `across` call.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` and `lengths`

```
library(purrr)
map(df, unique) %>% lengths
# x y z 
#3 1 2
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]
```